# How is it possible to add a trading chart widget on my website with delayed price data?

Tags: charts, trading, tradingview-api

For example, add the trading view chart widget or use its chart library to draw a trading widget with data delayed by 5 minutes.

Comment: have a look here. https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

Comment: @Yeak Yes, I have done that before but in that page it doesn't say anything about how I can get the widget to draw delayed price data.